# Header Access-Control-Request-Headers don't came in response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, cors

I configured my Spring Boot as the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    
        // Other configurations here
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://dwdelivery.com.br"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

But when browser sends a request, the response doesn't came with header `Access-Control-Request-Headers` as shown bellow.

[image]

Why is this happening?